# Appium and for loop

Tags: java, appium

Please help me to write appium-java code for  for loop in android app. I have a `ListView` like an image below and I want to click each download button sequentially and come back to the same page but I was stuck as I am new to Appium. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
    [image: Current screen for actions]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of your download buttons and click them depending on what view do they redirect you to(if they do.)

*Assuming* : Clicking download would simply start a download in background or take you to another UI view from where you can navigate back in one click. [Could be handled accordingly]

The relative code would be like :

```
List <WebElement> downloadButtons = driver.findElements(<your locator strategy>);
for(int i = 0; i<downloadButtons.size(); i++) {
    downloadButtons.get(i).click(); //performs a click on the i-th button
    driver.navigate.back(); //if previous click takes you to another view
}
```

**Your locator strategy could be any amongst {ByClass, ById, ByXPath, ByCss, ByName}**

Comment: List <WebElement> downloadButtons = driver.findElements(By.id("com.intex.istore:id/btnstart"));
  for(int i = 0; i<downloadButtons.size(); i++) {
      downloadButtons.get(i).click(); 
      List <WebElement> appDetails = driver.findElements(By.id("android:id/action_bar_title"));
      for(int j = 0; j<appDetails.size(); j++) {
      appDetails .get(j).click(); 
      
      }
       
  }

Comment: sometimes download button was clicked and sometimes not.when it was clicked it was not coming back to the download button.Looping is not working for me.

Comment: could you elaborate the navigation after clicking a download button on the current screen as shared by you in the question?

Comment: Sometimes my code works and first download button on the current screen was clicked and open a new screen but sometimes download button was not clicked.

Comment: Could you share the appium inspector screenshot for the same view to help understand better.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of appium inspector